# Dplyr mutating using another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Say I want to mutate a column ev1 for stim1 by finding the corresponding number in the Stimuli dataframe and finding its reward. For example

stim1 in data looks like this

```
  stim1
1     2
2     1
3     3
4     2
5     1
```

Stimuli looks like this

```
    number    reward
1        0 0.0000000
2        1 0.3333333
3        2 0.6666667
4        3 1.0000000...
```

Desired outcome

```
  stim1   ev1
1     2    0.6666667
2     1    0.3333333
3     3    1.0000000
4     2    0.6666667
5     1    0.3333333
```

My attempt of

```
data %>%  
  mutate(ev1=Stimuli$reward[which(Reward$number==stim1)]) -> data_modified
```

yields an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does the second row of stim1 from 4 become 1 and the fourth from 5 to 2?

Comment: that was a typo, thank you for pointing that out! just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a `left_join`:

`left_join()`
returns all rows from x, and all columns from x and y. Rows in x with no match in y will have NA values in the new columns. If there are multiple matches between x and y, all combinations of the matches are returned.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(stim1, Stimuli, by=c("stim1"="number"))
```

Output:

```
stim1    reward
1     2 0.6666667
2     1 0.3333333
3     3 1.0000000
4     2 0.6666667
5     1 0.3333333
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!